# Do I need a converter to do wide-angle photography?

Tags: wide-angle-converter

I have an AF-S Nikkor 18-105mm f/3.5-5.6G ED lens with my Nikon D90. Do I need a converter to wide angle photography ?

Comment: 18 is pretty wide already...how much wider do you want to shoot?

Comment: If you want to shoot ultra wide you probably want to get a lens with focal length 10-20mm, like 10-24 by Tamron, 10-20 by Sigma or 11-16 by Tokina.

Comment: @ssn [Please post answers in the answers section](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4655/please-put-your-answers-in-the-answers-section-even-if-theyre-short)

Comment: What do you mean by "converter"?

Comment: Dear Hueco I would like to shoot from inside Hotel Rooms to include as much possible space from and angle of a roughly 28 m2 bedroom; do I need the Ultra for it, or my Wide is sufficient. Dear xiota I saw in several reviews of wide angle converters that are lenses attached to normal lenses.

Comment: @HalkiosKypros for that you need a wide lens, see answer below

Answer (score 6):

No, you don’t need a converter. You probably need a different type of lens depending on what you define as "wide". 18mm with your crop-sensor Nikon equals 24mm on full frame, which is already in the space called Wide Angle.

However you might be thinking of Ultra Wide Angle, where you can get significant distortion on your subjects. For example like this

[image: My dog]

For Nikon crop sensor cameras you have some relatively inexpensive options such as:

1. Sigma 10-20mm (15-30mm Full Frame equivalent)
2. Tamron 10-24mm (15-36mm Full Frame equivalent)
3. Tokina 11-16mm (16.5-24mm Full Frame equivalent

This is not a comprehensive list and many other options may be available.
Number 1 and 2 should both autofocus on your Nikon camera, number 3 needs to be a specific version (Pro DX II) for AF to work with your camera.

Answer (score -2):

Your 18-105mm lens on an apsc d90 is equivalent to 27-157mm on a ff sensor
Normal or standard is 43.26mm
So the range is often referred to as 35-60mm is normal or standard

Telephoto is longer focal lengths so 61-600

Wide is consider under 35 so 15-35mm

Fisheye is a warped image and it can be from 5-20mm but a square will now look like a barrel

Ultra wide is considered as wider than 22mm
So 14-22 ultra wide
23-35 wide
35-60 std
60-600 tele

Zoom mens lens zooms in/out to various lengths
Your lens covers;
 27-35 wide
35-60 std
61-157 tele

“Wide” is what you think
I feel wide is 20mm
Other people dont like wider than 28mm
Its a feeling. Like what is fat or skinny

Aside from buying a lens wider than 18mm
(A lower number) like 10-22 (equiv 15-33)

You can shoot a panorama (cellphones do thiis well)
You can move closer, it makes things LOOK wider
You can STITCH together many pics
You can buy a cheaper converter lens to screw on.

There are two groups to third party lenses
The classics Sigma Tamron Tokina
New new comers Rokinon etc
The newer ones are cheaper and often manual focus
The classics cost more but have Autofocus
IF you buy a 12mm non fish eye lens 
Most things will be in focus. (Wider lenses have more depth of field). You can probably enjoy and get great photos with the manual focus.

The question is,, HOW wide do you want?
Then you can get a more precise snswer. 
IF the add on wide angle converter will fo enough
Or if you need a zoom or which fixed focal length prime you want 8mm 12mm 16mm 
(12mm 18mm 24mm equivs)

I hope this helps

Comment: it does help I appreciate all the help from all; I would like to shoot from inside Hotel Rooms to include as much possible space from and angle of a roughly 28 m2 bedroom